# append() is not working properly in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm using append first this is copy one line but second time this is copy two line. what is the wrong?

I want just single line clone on button click how can i do this?

My Code:-

```js
$(function() {
  $('.add-more-room-btn').click(function() {
    let addMoreRoomClone = $(this).parents('.room-info').find('.row:first').html();
    $(this).parents('.room-info').find('.row').append(addMoreRoomClone);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="room-info">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" placeholder="this need to copy" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="add-more-room-btn">Add More</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `.find('.row')` gets you all "rows" in `.room-info`. You add a new one every time you click the button... Simply append the new row (use `.clone()` instead of `.html()`) to `.room-info`.

Comment: There's a _"Tidy"_ button in the snippet editor. Please us it before you add your snippet into your question.

Comment: The issue is that you're selecting `.row` then appending it *inside* `.row`.  Your second selector then finds all rows, but one is inside the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it helps you, please check the snippet.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.add-more-room-btn').click(function() {
    let addMoreRoomClone = $(this).parents('.room-info').find('.row .col-md-12:first').clone();
    $(this).parents('.room-info').find('.row').append(addMoreRoomClone);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="room-info">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" placeholder="this need to copy" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="add-more-room-btn">Add More</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

obviously you append to .row, so next klick all those contents will be copied, look at my example which prepends to .room-info it will kinda work

```js
$(function() {
  $('.add-more-room-btn').click(function() {
    let addMoreRoomClone = $(this).parents('.room-info').find('.row:first').html();
    $(this).parents('.room-info').prepend(addMoreRoomClone);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="room-info">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" placeholder="this need to copy" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="add-more-room-btn">Add More</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your "lines" are `.row .col-md-12:first`, but you are selecting first `.row` (that is only one row in whole document) and appending it's `.html()`. Change selector and properly copy it's contents:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.add-more-room-btn').click(function() {
    // Make copy of whole element
    let newContent = $('<div>').append($(this).parents('.room-info').find('.row .col-md-12:first').clone()).html();
    console.log(newContent);
    $(this).parents('.room-info').find('.row').append(newContent);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="room-info">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" placeholder="this need to copy" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="add-more-room-btn">Add More</button>

</div>
```

Comment: `let newContent = $('<div>').append($(this).parents('.room-info').find('.row .col-md-12:first').clone()).html();` - What is this?! o.O